# See processes from given user on all machines

Tags: linux, process, server, ps

On a linux server with different computers: is there a way to see all processes running from a given user on all machines?

Comment: If you know statically the list of all hostnames, you could write a script (using `rsh` or `ssh`, then `ps`) to list them.

Comment: That's something like what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's too late for the answer, but for the records...
You can get it in this way:

```
hosts='192.168.1.x 192.168.1.y' # your hosts here
for host in $hosts; do
    echo $host:
    ssh some_user@$host 'ps -u given_user' # some_user for ssh, given_user for ps
done
```

In this way, you're creating an [`ssh`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) session for each host:

> ssh ... [user@]hostname [command]
>
> If command is specified, command is executed on the remote host instead
>   of a login shell.

...and executing [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) with the `-u` option:

> -u userlist
>   Select by effective user ID (EUID) or name.
>   This selects the processes whose effective user name or ID is in userlist.